# Generate array of unique phrases from consecutive words grouped by word count

Tags: php, arrays, combinations, cpu-word, match-phrase

I'm setting up a word search using PHP's `explode()`, and counting how many spaces from query and how many words in the query.

For example, my user search `Hello world, good morning` (query from user, maybe more words)

and I get:

- hello
- world
- good
- morning

I want to show the unique sets of words as arrays like:

1. `['hello world good morning']`
2. `['hello world good', 'world good morning']`
3. `['hello world', 'good morning', 'world good']`
4. `['hello', 'world', 'good', 'morning']`

For no 1 and 4 I can solve it, but no 2 and 3 it's so hard to thing.

```
$oriSearch = 'Hello world, good morning';
$search_query = trim(strtolower($oriSearch));
$search_query = preg_replace_callback('#([\W_]+)#', function() {
return ' ';
}, $search_query);

$totalSpace = substr_count($search_query, ' ');
$totalWord = ceil($totalSpace+1);

if($totalSpace > 0)
{
    $wordPlode = explode(' ', $search_query);
    $wordQuery = array();
    for($i=1;$i<=$totalWord;$i++)
    {
        if($i == $totalWord)
        {
            $wordQuery[] = $search_query;
        }
        else if($i == 1) {
            $wordQuery[] = $wordPlode;
        }
        else
        {
            //Here I need
        }
    }
    echo var_dump($wordQuery);
}
```

Comment: 2 is the hard one, because your adding to the array.  The others I can do with 2 lines....  `$array = explode(' ',$clean_string); for($i=1; $i<=count($array); ++$i) $output[] = array_map(function($a){return implode(' ', $a);},array_chunk($array,$i));`  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85e7572342cf5353c71714bf9907fa437b9c0e6d)  -- it's #3 in mine -- :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$clean_string = 'hello world good morning';

$array = explode(' ',$clean_string);

$len = count($array);

for($i=1; $i<=$len; ++$i){
    $output[] = array_map(function($a) use($i,$array){
        if(count($a) != $i) $a =  array_slice($array, -$i);
        return implode(' ', $a);
    },array_chunk($array,$i));
}
print_r($output);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => world
            [2] => good
            [3] => morning
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello world
            [1] => good morning
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello world good
            [1] => world good morning
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello world good morning
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad109d3a16e38a4e481363d396ba24948975ce44)

Obviously if you want it ordered the other way you can start at the count of the array and decrement it, instead (in the for loop).

Like this:

```
for($i=$len; $i>0; --$i) 
$output[] = array_map(function($a) use($i,$array){
    if(count($a) != $i) $a =  array_slice($array, -$i);
    return implode(' ', $a);
},array_chunk($array,$i));
```

The output is just the reverse of the above one.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a67882f03c777ff49b996e4a2d250cea1884223)

Chunky!

it's pretty simple array chunk will take an array (from explode, single words) and make it muti-dimensional in the chunk size (`$i`) which is based of the length of the array.

Then we can array map over that imploding the sub arrays if they are the length of `$i`, if they are not (odd vs even deal) which only happens at the end of the array, we can use array slice with a negative `$i` (the length we want) to fill that in.  Negative starts at the end of the array.

For example when we chunk array #2 in the above output we get this in the for loop:

```
    # index 2 from above output
    #explode
    array("hello", "world", "good", "morning")

    #array_chunk
    Array
    (
        [0] => array("hello", "world", "good")
        [1] => array("morning")
    )

   #array_slice
    Array
    (
        [0] => array("hello", "world", "good")
        [1] => array("world", "good", "morning")
    )

   #implode
   Array
    (
        [0] => "hello world good"
        [1] => "world good morning"
    )
```

Which is only `1` not `3` (the value of `$i`) so we take the original array and slice it from the end for 3 items. `['world', 'good', 'morning']` and use that instead.

Then when we implode both of those, we get what we want.

PS. I didn't bother cleaning the string as you already have that worked out to a serviceable degree.

Answer (score 0):

Capture progressively longer substrings using a lookahead pattern and prepend each set of matches to the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/miKoG))

```
$string = 'hello world good morning';
$result = [];
$i = 0;
while (preg_match_all("/(?=\b(\w+(?: \w+){{$i}})\b)/", $string, $m)) {
    array_unshift($result, $m[1]);
    ++$i;
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'hello world good morning',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'hello world good',
    1 => 'world good morning',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'hello world',
    1 => 'world good',
    2 => 'good morning',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'hello',
    1 => 'world',
    2 => 'good',
    3 => 'morning',
  ),
)
```